# public static String return null on a File when accessed

Tags: java, null

I am doing a program to conetarme by network to a file of a machine in the network and when trying to use the value of : (name) it reads it as null, instead when I make a System.out.println (name); I read the value

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static String text;
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

     //int wc = DevolverValor.Leer();
     //String wcs = Integer.toString(wc);
     String name = "";


    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("La tikets");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(650 , 300);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // el panel no está visible en la salida
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(); // el panel no está visible en la

    JLabel etiqueta =  new JLabel("Introducir nombre de la maquina");
    JLabel cantidad = new JLabel("Cantidad");

    JButton Buscar = new JButton("Buscar");
    JButton restablecer = new JButton("Restablecer");

    JTextField tf = new JTextField(15); // acepta hasta 10 caracteres

    panel.add(etiqueta); // Componentes agregados usando Flow Layout
    panel.add(cantidad); // Componentes agregados usando
    panel.add(tf);
    panel.add(Buscar);
    panel.add(restablecer);

    panel2.add(cantidad);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_END, panel2);
    frame.setVisible(true);




    Buscar.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            DevolverValor.Leer();
            text = tf.getText();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    });


    restablecer.addActionListener(e -> tf.setText(""));



}


    public static String getNombre() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

This is where I try to use the value of (text) of the Main class and then use it in DeolverValue.java which I call it as (name)

DevolverValor.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DevolverValor {

public static int Leer() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String word1 = "Data:";
    String name = Main.getNombre();
    int wordCount = 0;


    File text = new File("\\\\"+name+"\\C$\\SITA\\BSIA.log.1");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        if (s.next().equals(word1)) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(name);

    return wordCount;
}

}
```

When running the program returns the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwZ3J.png)

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem: do you want to say that `System.out.println(name);` prints the name but `"\\\\"+name+"\\C$\\SITA\\BSIA.log.1"` turns into "\\null\\C$..."?

Comment: Also I recommend that you read more about `static` and what it means. You are overusing it here.

Comment: "when trying to use the value of : (name) it reads it as null" how do you know? What actually happens?

Comment: On a side note (which is part of what Code-Apprentice is getting at): instead of using a static field to pass around data, why don't you change `Leer()` to `leer(String name)` (I adjusted the name for Java code conventions as well) and then call it like `DevolverValor.leer(tf.getText());`?

Comment: You've written `DevolverValor.Leer(); text = tf.getText();`. So first you're *reading* the value of `text` in `Leer` and then you're *writing* the value afterwards.

Comment: Another side note: DO NOT do heavy work in Swing event listeners as those will block the event dispatch thread and make your UI appear frozen. Use SwingWorker etc. instead - see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
            DevolverValor.Leer();
            text = tf.getText();
```

You call the `Leer()` function which in turn calls `getName()` which returns the value of `text`. Only after you do all of this do you set the value of `text`.

Instead, you need to do these in the opposite order:

```
            text = tf.getText();
            DevolverValor.Leer();
```

However, it would make more sense to just pass the value of text as a parameter to `Leer()`:

```
text = tf.getText();
DevolverValor.Leer(text);
```

This requires changing

```
public static int Leer() throws FileNotFoundException {
```

to

```
public static int Leer(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

and removing `String name = Main.getNombre();` from inside the function.

This will fix your immediate problem. I have a few additional tips and suggestions:

1. Use descriptive names for variables. `text` isn't very descriptive. Find something that better describes what this variable represents.
2. Learn about how to properly use classes, create instances, and access methods and fields. Also learn about what `static` means. All of your methods are currently `static`. Generally, there should only be one static method named `main()`. All other methods should not be static, at least for now. There are good uses for static, but as a beginner you probably will over use this. If you force yourself to not use it for a while, you will learn better habits in writing your code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!, it already works well, sorry if I have not explained myself very well I am starting in Java, and I do not know very well what I do

Comment: @Lozeer55 Keep working at it and you'll figure it out. Please read my suggestions at the end of my answer for some tips to help you improve.

Answer (score 1):

Text is unasinged when you try to read the first time.

```
Buscar.addActionListener(e -> {
    try {
        DevolverValor.Leer(); //text is null
        text = tf.getText(); // text is asigned know
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
});
```

I don't know all the code, but I move asignation to up and then text is asigned when you reat it.

In addition to eite this problem I pass the string like param:

```
Buscar.addActionListener(e -> {
    try {
        DevolverValor.Leer(tf.getText());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
});
```

And then:

```
public static int Leer(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String word1 = "Data:";
    int wordCount = 0;

    File text = new File("\\\\"+name+"\\C$\\SITA\\BSIA.log.1");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);

    while (s.hasNext()) {

        if (s.next().equals(word1)) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(name);

    return wordCount;
}
```